# Why $f^*$ must be the identity map in Q.3.2.3(a) in AT? And notation question.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, projective-space, group-cohomology, topological-k-theory

Here is the question I am trying to understand its solution:

Using the cup product structure, show there is no map $\mathbb R P^n \to \mathbb R P^m$ inducing a nontrivial map $H^1(\mathbb R P^m; \mathbb Z/ 2 \mathbb Z ) \to H^1(\mathbb R P^n; \mathbb Z/ 2 \mathbb Z )$ if $n > m.$ What is the corresponding result for maps $\mathbb C P^n \to \mathbb C P^m.$

here is an answer I found online:

> [image]

Here are my questions about it:

1- In the third line, why the induced map $f^*$ has to be the identity map?

2- Does Allen Hatcher book  "Algebraic Topology" has the same notion for cohomology groups and cohomology rings (Thm. 3.12)?

Comment: but my second question is different? Why closing it?

Comment: Regarding your second question, there is no Thm 3.12. The notation $H^*(-)$ means all of cohomology, thought of either as a ring or as a graded group, depending on the context. $H^n(-)$ means the $n$th cohomology group.